# Silverlight maxItemsInObjectGraph behaviour

Tags: vb.net, wcf, silverlight, ria

I currently have a silverlight application which has silverlight class library. The silverlight class library has a WCF service reference which works as expected for small data.

However we have come across a problem which is caused by the default value of maxItemsInObjectGraph. We have tested it with an increased value (called from vb app set in behaviour) and it works however we are unsure how to set the value of maxItemsInObjectGraph when it is in a silverlight class library (as it is only defined in the clientconfig file and no services are added to the client).

I have seen posts about adding it to the web.config but this only seems to apply when the service is called directly by the app not by a class library?

Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could set maxItemsInObjectGraph automatically:

```
ChannelFactory<IMyService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpoint);
foreach (var operation in channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
{
    var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find() as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;
    if ( behavior != null )
    {
        behavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Werlang, this seems to require the binding and endpoint to be hardcoded too. Is there anyway I can pick the binding/endpoint up from the serviceconfig as well as implementing the above?

Comment: Also the DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior is not available in the Silverlight 4 .net framework?